# Characterization of $L[T_{2n+1}]$ as a direct limit of mice

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, inner-model-theory

I am asking for a reference request/proof sketch for the result of Steel 
that characterizes $L[T_{2n+1}]$ as a direct limit of mice.

Given that both $L[T_{2n+1}]$ and $M_{2n}$ have a $\Sigma_{2n+2}$ well-ordering of the reals, I think the result should be that $L[T_{2n+1}]$ is the direct limit of iterable mice with $2n$ Woodin cardinals, but I am not sure.

I'm starting to think that this result is not written up, in which case a proof sketch would be appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

Cody

Comment: This result is mentioned in Steel's paper "$HOD^{L(R)}$ is a core model below $\Theta$". It is not proved explicitly there but the same method applies.